# Autonomous System: Finding all orbits connected to a fixed point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Given the autonomous system
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \dot{x}\\ \dot{y} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} y\\ |x| \end{pmatrix} $$
I found that all orbits in the left halfplane are circular
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\| (x,y) \|^2 = 0 \quad (x \leq 0) $$
Those in the first quadrant are growing in modulus
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\| (x,y) \|^2 = 4xy > 0 \quad (x,y > 0) $$
while those in the forth quadrant are decreasing
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\| (x,y) \|^2 = 4xy < 0 \quad (x > 0, y < 0) $$
**Question:** How can I prove that the only orbits approaching the fixed point (0,0) for $t \to \infty$ or $t \to -\infty$ are the diagonals in the first and forth quadrant in an elementary ODE-style way (no Poincaré-Bendixon or so)?

Comment: You can construct a solution to the differential equation by stitching the two linear differential equations. By looking at the corresponding eigen vectors you can determine which initial condition has a solution, which does not switch between solutions of the linear differential equations.

Answer (score 0):

Arrgh, I found a first integral
$$ E(x,y) = y^2 - \mathrm{sgn}(x)x^2 $$
which is constant along every orbit. Any solution approaching $(0,0)$ will satisfy
$$ E(x_0, y_0) = \lim_t E(x(t), y(t)) = E(0,0) = 0 $$
and so we have
$$ x_0 \geq 0 \wedge ( y_0 = -x_0 \vee y_0 = +x_0 )  $$
and using the monotonicity of the modulus we find the solution.